# Why does DataDog prefer the Docker-based Agent installation?

Tags: docker, datadog

According to the [DataDog Docker Integration Docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/docker_daemon/#installation):

> There are two ways to run the [DataDog] Agent: directly on each host, or within a docker-dd-agent container. We recommend the latter.

Why is a Docker-based agent installation preferred over just installing the DataDog agent directly as a service on the box that's running the Docker containers?

Comment: Probably because with the Docker deployment they have full control over all the software dependencies.

Comment: I'd guess it's the difference between running one command to get their exact environment up across all Linux' and having users run installations across the limitless number of configs that exist in the world. From Datadogs point of view I expect it would be much easier to create and support a Docker image that they use to test internally, from a users point of view it's easier to setup.

Comment: @Matt That makes sense. I guess it is just about guaranteeing the artifact that's installed, versus being exposed to countless unknowns.

Comment: Also uninstalling is finished by simply stopping and deleting the container.

Answer (score 1):

One of Dockers main features is portability and it makes sense to bind datadog into that environment. That way they are packaged and deployed together and you don't have the overhead of installing datadog manually everywhere you choose to deploy.

What they are also implying is that you should use **[docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/)** and turn your application / docker container into an multi-container Docker application, running your image(s) alongside the docker agent. Thus you will not need to write/build/run/manage a container via Dockerfile, but rather add the agent image to your **docker-compose.yml** along with its configuration. Starting your multi-container application will still be easy via:

```
docker-compose up
```

Its really convenient and gives you additional features like their [autodiscovery](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/autodiscovery/?tab=docker) service.